# Joining multiple tables in postgreSQL with same column names

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to join multiple tables in postgreSQL with same column names but getting an error "column reference "name" is ambiguous", I tried different solutions but still not able to figure out.

The tables with same column names are vessel_info, vessel_company, and vessel_gangway_type.

Below is the code:

```
SELECT
vi.id AS id, 
vi.name AS name,

max(vc.name) AS owner,
max(vc.company_id) AS owner_id,

max(vt.vessel_type_name) AS vessel_type_name,
max(vt.vt_id) AS vessel_type_id,

max(vcn.class_name) AS class_name,
max(vcn.id) AS class_name_id,

max(vgt.name) AS gangway_type_name,
max(vgt.id) AS gangway_type_id,

array_agg(vf.file) AS files,
array_agg(vf.file_id) AS file_ids,
array_agg(vf.file_size) AS file_sizes

FROM vessel_info vi

LEFT JOIN vessel_file vf
ON vf.vessel_id_2 = vi.id

LEFT JOIN vessel_fixtures vfx
ON vfx.vessel_id = vi.id

LEFT JOIN vessel_company vc
ON vc.company_id = vi.owner_id_2

LEFT JOIN vessel_types vt
ON vt.vt_id = vi.vessel_type_id

LEFT JOIN vessel_class_name vcn
ON vcn.id = vi.class_name_id

LEFT JOIN vessel_gangway_type vgt
ON vgt.id = vi.gangway_type_id
```

I tried to remove:

```
max(vc.name) AS owner and max(vgt.name) AS gangway_type_name
```

but still it says "name is ambiguous", they have same column that is "id" but not getting an error. it says "name"

Comment: I don't think you are showing your entire query. Perhaps the problem is in your `GROUP BY` or your `WHERE`?

Comment: Prefix every column  reference with the source table or table alias. This should happen in every query involving multiple tables or joins. & Add the actual error message to your question

Comment: Try changing, at least temporarily, "vi.name AS name" to "vi.name AS vi_name"